# VB.NET Controls inside of a DataGridView Row on a Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ComboBox inside of a cell of a DataGridView Row on a Windows form.  I need the following to happen:

1. click on the ComboBox
2. pick a value
3. recalculate a total & display inside of a lable that is sitting
       outside of the DataGridView.

Currently, the following is happening:

1. Click on the ComboBox
2. Click it again to open the CB's Drop-down list
3. select a value
4. click outside of the cell to force a recalculation of the
       external label.

I want to avoid, first, having to click the combo twice (once to set focus, and again to select the value).  Second, I'd like for a live recalculation to happen after selecting a value.

Does anyone have a trick or two to solve any of these?

I've tried most of the events on the DGV without much luck.

Comment: You should really search before you ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241100/how-to-manually-drop-down-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler to the CellClick event of the DataGridView that looks a bit like:

```
private void vehicleTypeGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.RowIndex == - 1 ) return; //Header Cell clicked -> ignore it.
    vehicleTypeGridView.BeginEdit ( true );
    var control = vehicleTypeGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if ( control != null ) control.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set your datagridview editmode:

```
datagridview.EditMode = Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
```

Next, set the sendkey to F4 for the combobox:

```
Private Sub datagridview_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
        Handles datagridview.EditingControlShowing
    Dim CB As Object = TryCast(e.Control, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
    If CB IsNot Nothing Then
        My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{F4}")
    End If
End Sub
```