# How to change the behaviour of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a data grid that contains a Combo Box Column, but editing this Combo Box (by simply clicking on it) gets annoying sometimes, since one must click at least twice to change the value of that field. I want to change that behaviour, so I thought it would be very simple: just create a OnMouseOver event to make the mouse-overed combo box be selected, but the only available event is the Disposed one.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: are you working on a webapplication or winapplication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just dealt with the same problem, and solved it by setting the `DataGridView.EditMode` to `EditOnEnter`.

If you don't like that behaviour for all your other columns, I found [this suggestion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/68c463e2-84d5-4865-9fe9-1ea23e56a9a0) for placing in the `CellEnter` event:

```
if (DataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
{
    ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)DataGridView1.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
}
```

I haven't tried it, but it looks promising. The same technique is discussed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241100/4794).

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms, there's a CellMouseEnter event (and a CellEnter event for non-mouse navigation) on the DataGridView. You can use that to set the selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting only the Disposed event (I think) is because you are trying to go too deep.  I get only the Disposed event when I try to go all the way to dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"]...

Instead, as KeithS mentioned, you can assign the CellMouseEnter event to your DataGridView.

From there, you can do the following...

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex==0 || e.ColumnIndex==2)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```

That if-statement is just there to show how to restrict this functionality to certain columns, in case you want that.

The first line inside the if-statement sets the current cell and the second line begins the edit process.

This is a general process that should work with any type of column you can throw into a DataGridView.  The DataGridView's EditMode shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This works really good.
On the CellClick event of the datagridview:

```
void datagridview1_CellClick(object sender, .Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){if (e.ColumnIndex > 0)
        {
            W1.dGVReports.CurrentCell = W1.dGVReports.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            W1.dGVReports.BeginEdit(true);
            (W1.dGVReports.EditingControl as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```