# vb.net / DataGridView / ComboBox Column?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Data Grid View and some of the columns are of type ComboBox. What happends is that when I click on a cell that's a ComboBox it Selects the ComboBox but I have to click it again for it dropdown and show the Combox Items. How can I have it do this with one click?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the behaviour of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034401/how-to-change-the-behaviour-of-the-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your DataGridView's [EditMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y487)  to [DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).