# Can't see dropdown items in Datagridviewcomboboxcell

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, combobox, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have created Datagridviewcomboboxcells as follows, each of  which have 2-3 items.
I'm able to see the Datagridviewcomboboxcells with the appropriate values inside the comboboxcell, but I'm not able to see the dropdown list when i click on the comboboxcell.

Should I write a separate event handler to display the dropdown list ? Does it not dropdown by default ?

```
        Dim Dgv2cb_ColdStart As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        Dgv2cb_ColdStart.Items.Add("C:\pd_DelAll.pl")
        Dgv2cb_ColdStart.Items.Add("No Cold Start")


        dgv2.Rows.Add("ColdStart")
        dgv2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1) = Dgv2cb_ColdStart
        If temp_profile.ColdStart = "" Then
            dgv2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Value = Dgv2cb_ColdStart.Items(1)
        Else
            dgv2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Value = Dgv2cb_ColdStart.Items(0)
        End If
```

Surprising thing is the same code on another backup of the project works, but that is an older version that i can't use now.
I'm not able to reproduce the error, as to what is causing the dropdown not to occur.

Comment: Have you tried clicking it twice? For me it doesn't show up on the first click.

Comment: This had apparantly been asked before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241100/how-to-manually-drop-down-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Comment: No, It does not dropdown even after double-click.

Comment: @WozzeC - I don't think so... this OP does not necessarily want to open the DDL manually - just willing to resort to that if no other solution is available.