# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - Have to click cell twice to display combo box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I am using a `DataGridView`, created using the designer with a few columns including a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` column.

It is slightly irritating that I have to click on each cell twice or even three times to display the drop-list:

1. If I click over the text part, it takes *3* clicks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

2. If I click on the down arroow, only two clicks:

[image]
[image]

I assume it's due to the cell using the first click to get focus, but is there a way to address the issue so clicking on a cell displays the combobox right away? I note that using `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` the same issue does *not* happen... clicking on a checkbox immediately toggles it regardless if that cell had focus.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/242760/3413552](http://stackoverflow.com/a/242760/3413552)

Comment: You may want to check [this solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543940/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-doesnt-open-the-dropdown-on-first-click/39757746#39757746)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply set [`EditMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of your `DataGridView` to `EditOnEnter`.

It makes editing more easy. Almost single click, but if you want even when you click on content of combobox show dropdown for your `ComboBoxColumn` immediately, you can handle [`CellClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event and then use [`EditingControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of your grid and cast it to [`DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrol?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and makes it to show dropdown.

```
private void categoryDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //You can check for e.ColumnIndex to limit this to your specific column
    var editingControl = this.categoryDataGridView.EditingControl as 
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (editingControl != null)
        editingControl.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

*Be careful when using this trick, you may make drop downs annoying for users when they only want to navigate between cells without editing.*